# What does this mean in Opencv Documentation?

Tags: c++, opencv

Im trying to understand goodFeaturesToTrack and in the documention at this link:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=goodf#goodfeaturestotrack

it says "

Note

If the function is called with different values A and B of the parameter qualityLevel , and A > {B}, the vector of returned corners with qualityLevel=A will be the prefix of the output vector with qualityLevel=B . "

is A > {B} just a is greater than b or does it mean something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there is a typo in the documentation, and B should not be in curly brackets. Probably, it was an intent to make this letter be of different font.

Since the `qualityLevel` parameter is `double`, and from RTFS (reading the fine sources :) ) I conclude that this text says the following.

If you call this function several times, decreasing `qualityLevel` step by step, then this function will return the same results, just truncating them somewhere at the end.

In other words, if you compare results from two such calls, you'll see the same elements in the beginning and different amount of the results.